# Visual Studio 2022 hangs with "Opening the file..." message

Tags: visual-studio, devexpress, dbml

When I Trying to open dbml files, Visual Studio 2022 hangs with "Opening the file..." message

it's not happen when I open any other files

I tryed to solve this problem by:

-Uninstall Devexpress

-Uninstall Visual studio 2022

and reinstall both of them

[image]

Comment: Same problem, do you have solution?

Comment: @NamLe Yes, I just disabled DevExpress extensions and now everything OK

Comment: Yup. For me, I had uninstalled VS and re-install VS and the problem was gone, DevExpress is still there.

Answer (score 0):

for my case in vs2022 17.5.1
I have old project and the rdlc reports still open file .
the solution is :
open new project .
add new rdlc report .
wait to finished .
close the new project.
re-open your old project .
now its work .